RAG pipeline using Haystack - error with Pipeline embedder
I'm trying to run a RAG pipeline using Haystack (and Milvus) on my cluster instance using python (3.10.12).
The Imports and relevant packages I have in this env are shown at the end of this question.
my code is: 

model embedding & generator functions:

@component
def model_embedder(self, documents,cache_dir=cache_dir):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)

    embeddings = []
    for doc in documents:
        inputs = tokenizer(doc.content, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(**inputs)
            embedding = output.pooler_output.squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
        embeddings.append(embedding)

    for doc, embedding in zip(documents, embeddings):
        doc.embedding = embedding
    return documents

@component
def model_generator(self, query, context=None, generation_kwargs={}, cache_dir=cache_dir):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)

    inputs = tokenizer(query, context=context, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model.generate(**inputs, **generation_kwargs)
    return tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)


RAG Pipeline:

rag_pipeline = Pipeline()
rag_pipeline.add_component("converter", MarkdownToDocument())
rag_pipeline.add_component(
    "splitter", DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2)
)
rag_pipeline.add_component("embedder", model_embedder)  
rag_pipeline.add_component(document_store)
rag_pipeline.add_component(
    "retriever", MilvusEmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store, top_k=3)
)
rag_pipeline.add_component("writer", DocumentWriter(document_store))
rag_pipeline.add_component("prompt_builder", PromptBuilder(template=prompt_template))
rag_pipeline.add_component(
    "generator",
    model_generator,
)

rag_pipeline.connect("converter.documents", "splitter.documents")  
rag_pipeline.connect("splitter.documents", "embedder.documents")   
rag_pipeline.connect("embedder", "writer")
rag_pipeline.connect("text_embedder.embedding", "retriever.query_embedding")
rag_pipeline.connect("retriever.documents", "prompt_builder.documents")
rag_pipeline.connect("prompt_builder", "generator")

rag_pipeline.draw('./rag_pipeline.png')


If I decorate with @component, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ComponentError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 @component
----> 2 def model_embedder(self, documents,cache_dir=cache_dir):
      4     tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(mymodel, cache_dir=cache_dir)

File /.../rag_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haystack/core/component/component.py:517, in _Component.__call__(self, cls, is_greedy)
    513     return self._component(cls, is_greedy=is_greedy)
    515 if cls:
    516     # Decorator is called without parens
--> 517     return wrap(cls)
    519 # Decorator is called with parens
    520 return wrap

File /.../rag_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haystack/core/component/component.py:513, in _Component.__call__.<locals>.wrap(cls)
    512 def wrap(cls):
--> 513     return self._component(cls, is_greedy=is_greedy)

File /.../rag_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haystack/core/component/component.py:464, in _Component._component(self, cls, is_greedy)
    462 # Check for required methods and fail as soon as possible
    463 if not hasattr(cls, "run"):
--> 464     raise ComponentError(f"{cls.__name__} must have a 'run()' method. See the docs for more information.")
    466 def copy_class_namespace(namespace):
...
    469 
    470     Simply copy the whole namespace from the decorated class.
    471     """

ComponentError: model_embedder must have a 'run()' method. See the docs for more information.

And if I dont use the @component decorator (and remove the self from both functions), these funcitons compile, but then when i run the rag_pipeline code, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PipelineValidationError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 6
      2 rag_pipeline.add_component("converter", MarkdownToDocument())
      3 rag_pipeline.add_component(
      4     "splitter", DocumentSplitter(split_by="sentence", split_length=2)
      5 )
----> 6 rag_pipeline.add_component("embedder", model_embedder)  
      7 rag_pipeline.add_component(document_store)
      8 rag_pipeline.add_component(
      9     "retriever", MilvusEmbeddingRetriever(document_store=document_store, top_k=3)
     10 )

File /.../rag_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/haystack/core/pipeline/base.py:313, in PipelineBase.add_component(self, name, instance)
    311 # Component instances must be components
    312 if not isinstance(instance, Component):
--> 313     raise PipelineValidationError(
    314         f"'{type(instance)}' doesn't seem to be a component. Is this class decorated with @component?"
    315     )
    317 if getattr(instance, "__haystack_added_to_pipeline__", None):
    318     msg = (
    319         "Component has already been added in another Pipeline. Components can't be shared between Pipelines. "
    320         "Create a new instance instead."
    321     )

PipelineValidationError: '<class 'function'>' doesn't seem to be a component. Is this class decorated with @component?

The imports I'm using are:
import os
import urllib.request

from haystack import Pipeline
from haystack.components.converters import MarkdownToDocument

from haystack.components.preprocessors import DocumentSplitter
from haystack.components.writers import DocumentWriter

from milvus_haystack import MilvusDocumentStore
from milvus_haystack.milvus_embedding_retriever import MilvusEmbeddingRetriever

from haystack.components.builders import PromptBuilder

import mdit_plain
from haystack import component

import huggingface_hub
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

Since I suspect there might be some issue (/incompatability) with the haystack libraries I use, I show here all the "haystack" related libraries and versions i have in the current environment:
Package                      Version
---------------------------- --------------
farm-haystack                1.26.3
haystack                     0.42
haystack-ai                  2.5.1
haystack-experimental        0.2.0
milvus-haystack              0.0.10

I'd be happy to get any suggestions / help how to resolve the issue and run the RAG pipeline.


The only package you need is haystack-ai (pip install haystack-ai). Installing  farm-haystack and haystack-ai in the same Python environment causes problems. See Get started page.

Here you can find some usage examples for Haystack + Milvus.

Looking at your code, you are trying to implement a custom Embedder + a custom Generator. I suggest looking at the docs to understand if the existing Haystack components are suitable your use case. For example, you might take a look at SentenceTransformersTextEmbedder, SentenceTransformersDocumentEmbedder, and HuggingFaceLocalGenerator.

If existing components do not fit your use case, take a look at Creating Custom Components guide. In short, a Component is an object and the execution logic must live inside the run method.

Your Pipeline tries to do indexing + RAG. It would be better to have different pipelines. Docs for RAG Pipeline - Tutorial on RAG - Tutorial on Indexing.



Feel free to join the Haystack Discord channel for further guidance and to interact with the community.
